# Angular typescript: cannot find module aspnetcore-https

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, package.json

In package.json I have:

```
{
  "name": "projName",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
...
```

when I run npm start I get:

Error: Cannot find module '...\aspnetcore-https'

How can I install the module?
If I try

```
npm install  aspnetcore-https
```

I get:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aspnetcore-https - Not found
```

I have this line I think because I copied the packages.json from a Visual Studio Angular Typescript project into a Typescript only source code folder, but the latter folder project should still work if I install the correct package?

Update: the project runs correctly from npm start if I just remove the line

```
"prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
```

but I'd like to understand why I can't install this module?

Comment: I don't think it's an npm package. But some sort of js file that doesn't exist in your template it seems

Comment: You can't install `aspnetcore-https` package since it's not in npm registry.

Answer (score 3):

Visual studio installs a aspnetcore-https.js file into the ClientApp folder.  This file is typically excluded from source control.  The file is missing from your project folder.

Below is the contents of my copy:

```
// This script sets up HTTPS for the application using the ASP.NET Core HTTPS certificate
const fs = require('fs');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const path = require('path');

const baseFolder =
  process.env.APPDATA !== undefined && process.env.APPDATA !== ''
    ? `${process.env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https`
    : `${process.env.HOME}/.aspnet/https`;

const certificateArg = process.argv.map(arg => arg.match(/--name=(?<value>.+)/i)).filter(Boolean)[0];
const certificateName = certificateArg ? certificateArg.groups.value : process.env.npm_package_name;

if (!certificateName) {
  console.error('Invalid certificate name. Run this script in the context of an npm/yarn script or pass --name=<<app>> explicitly.')
  process.exit(-1);
}

const certFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.pem`);
const keyFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.key`);

if (!fs.existsSync(certFilePath) || !fs.existsSync(keyFilePath)) {
  spawn('dotnet', [
    'dev-certs',
    'https',
    '--export-path',
    certFilePath,
    '--format',
    'Pem',
    '--no-password',
  ], { stdio: 'inherit', })
  .on('exit', (code) => process.exit(code));
}
```

Comment: Note that if you create a new Angular/whatever front end app in VS it will create this file for you which can copy across to your project. I mention this in case this code changes in future

Answer (score 2):

If you took this package file from a Visual Studio app, it probably means that they used a custom project generator (not @angular/cli) and they added a custom file called `aspnetcore-https.js`.

If you move the package file away from its original folder, it becomes unable to find this file.

This is your issue.